# How to remember old select option after submitting?

Tags: php, laravel

but nothing worked so far to show the selected option after submitting the form with select boxes. Does anyone has an idea?

```
                <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" id="">
                    <option value="0">Selecteer categorie</option>
                    @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
                            <option value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

This is my controller:

```
    public function allartworks(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->has('category_id') || $request->has('style_id') || $request->has('technic_id')) {
            
                if(request()->category_id != "0") {
                    $category = request()->category_id;
                    $categorycomparison = "=";
                } else {
                    $category = 0;
                    $categorycomparison = "!=";
                }

                if(request()->style_id != "0") {
                    $style = request()->style_id;
                    $stylecomparison = "=";
                } else {
                    $style = 0;
                    $stylecomparison = "!=";
                }

                if(request()->technic_id != 0) {
                    $technic = request()->technic_id;
                    $technic_comparison = "=";
                } else {
                    $technic = 0;
                    $technic_comparison = "!=";
                }

                $artworks = Artwork::get()->where('category_id', $categorycomparison, $category)->where('style_id', $stylecomparison, $style)->where('technic_id', $technic_comparison, 'technic')->sortBy('price'); 
                
            } else {
                $artworks = Artwork::all();
            }
            return view('frontend.index', compact('artworks'));
    }
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. When you say _“nothing worked so far”_, then you must have tried some stuff - so _show us_ what that actually is/was.

Comment: For every `<option>` you have to check its value (`$cat->id`) against the value you saved. If they're the same, then set the `selected` attribute on that `<option>`.

Comment: `<option <?= (isset($_POST['category_id']) && $cat->id == $_POST['category_id'] ? 'selected' : '') ?> value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->name }}</option>`

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal, how have you determined that the saved value is named 'category_id', or even that it is passed through `$_POST`?

Comment: i have a javascript function that store all input changes and send it in one variable to php

Comment: @RoAchterberg I dont know if its post, its the standard. You know the index because of `<select name="category_id" ...>`

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal, while that may be likely, my point is that you _don't know_ and should await debug info instead of basing an answer on assumptions. Especially when dealing with somebody who is clearly just starting out.

Comment: @RoAchterberg i dont know why you specifically have something against my provided comment. While there is person out there suggesting to know an answer to this incomplete question. We both know this question is incomplete so what else can we do expect assume things? :)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal, I have nothing 'against' your comment (or you). If you know the question is incomplete, then you should've asked for clarification, instead of answering something so absolutely.

Comment: <option <?= (isset($_POST['category_id']) && $cat->id == $_POST['category_id'] ? 'selected' : '') ?> value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->name }}</option>      this had no result eather. It provides no error but the option after submitting reverses into selecteer categorie

Comment: @RoAchterberg my bad, ill remember that in the future.

Comment: @GijsMachielsen try `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` then (for both uses)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal - By offering solutions before we know what they actually are doing (specially in comments), we risk generating unnecessary noise in the comments, which can make the OP focus on the wrong things. It's also makes it harder for other people who asked for info to get it since the OP might focus on your suggestion instead (that might be completely off). Solutions should also be posted as answers instead of in comments (but again, not until we have enough info.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller side, you add the following line.

```
$request->flash();
```

The flash method will flash the current input to the session.

On the view, you use the following code.

```
     <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" id="">
            <option value="0">Selecteer categorie</option>
            @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
                    <option value=" {{ $cat->id }} " {{ old('category_id') == $cat->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $cat->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't remembered the old value. So solution did not worked.

Comment: Same comment as your other answer; `collect()->contains()` here is irrelevant, as this is not a mult-select :)

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you again! ^^

Comment: No problem! And I will say, for multi-selects, this approach would work great, with 1 modification: `(collect(old('category_id', []))->contains($cat->id))`; passing an empty array as the 2nd argument of `old()` so it doesn't break if nothing was selected.

Comment: @Gijs Machielsen I updated my post. Could you check again the result?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work neither. I am using laravel 7. Perhaps that's an issue. @ThânLƯƠNG

Comment: @GijsMachielsen could you please share your controller?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG I have put my controller now in the post above. Kind regards.

Comment: @GijsMachielsen you add `$request->flash();` before `if(request()->category_id != "0") {`.

Comment: Thankyou very much! @ThânLƯƠNG you helped me very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `selected` attribute to the selected option. Pass the selected id back to the view and you can do something like that

```
 <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" id="">
        <option value="0">Selecteer categorie</option>
        @foreach(App\Category::all() as $category)
        <option value="{{ $cat->id }}" {{ $cat->id == $selectedId ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $cat->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
```

Comment: This did not worked. error >>>  Undefined variable: selectedId

Comment: as mentionned, you have to pass the selected id back to the view `$selectedId`

Comment: @ml59 You changed `$cat` to `$category`, but you're still referencing `$cat->id`, also, you aren't showing how you've defined `$selectedId` (you're describing it, but it's better to show the code).

Comment: the $category was a mistake. Still the problem occors when I use $cat. I have tried to put my controller section, but stackoverflow is complaining that it is too much code and to less description.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check by `old()` function

```php
             <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" id="">
                    <option value="0">Selecteer categorie</option>
                    @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
                            <option value="{{ $cat->id }}" {{old('category_id') == $cat->id  ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $cat->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

Comment: @GijsMachielsen This approach will work if you're using `->withInput()` in your Controller, but since you didn't post that code in your question, we can only guess. Please try to provide enough information for us to actually help you.

Comment: @TimLewis with effort I have updated my first post. Now you can find my controller.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why should one use that `old` function?